# Show that a Torus has an Isometry of Order4.

Tags: geometry

If the fundamental region for a torus T is a square, show that T has an isometry of order 4 induced by a rotation of the plane.

Secondly, if the fundamental region is a rhombus with angles $\pi/3$ and $2\pi/3$, show that T has an isometry of order 6 induced by a rotation of the plane.

We have defined the torus T as T=$R^2$$ /  \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is generated by two linearly independent translations, $t_1$ and $t_2$. The fundamental region of a T is a parallelogram, but in this special case we are assuming that this parallelogram is actually a square. I have no clue where to start with this problem, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $R^2$ is generated by $u,v$ and $\Gamma$ is generated by the translations $t_u$ and $t_v$. The linear map $f$ defined by the matrix $A=\pmatrix{0 & -1\cr 1& 0}$ in $u,v$ is the matrix of the rotation of angle ${\pi\over 2}$.
Since $f\Gamma f^{-1}=\Gamma$, $f$ induces an automorphism of $T^2$. Its order is 4.

Comment: I don't know why the matrix A is the matrix of the rotation $\pi/2$

Comment: $\pmatrix{ cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) \cr sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)}$ is the matrix of the rotation of angle $\theta$. Take $\theta=\pi/2$.

Comment: Got it. That part makes sense now. How does this lead us to conclude that the order of f is 4 though?

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate this explicitly using complex algebra and roots of unity.

Since all that matters is the square's shape, we can WLOG assume $\Gamma$ is generated by $t(z)=z+1$ and $t_2(z)=z+i$. We wish to show the rotation $r(z)=iz$ induces an isometry of order $4$ in $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$.

Let $$z=a+bi,\quad u=c+di$$ be points in the fundamental square $S$. The distance between any two $\Gamma$-orbits of $z$ and $u$ is $$d(z',u')=\sqrt{(a+N_1-c-N_2)^2+(b+N_3-d-N_4)^2},\tag{*}$$ where $N_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Under the rotation $r$ we get $$rz=-b+ai,\quad ru=-d+ci.$$ The distance between $\Gamma$-orbits of rotated points is $$d(rz',ru')=\sqrt{(b+N_3-d-N_4)^2+(a+N_1-c-N_2)^2}\tag{**}.$$ As the minimums of $*$ and $**$ are equal, $r$ induces an isometry of $\mathbb{T}$.

To show $r$ has order $4$, it suffices to follow the orbits of $z\in S$ under rotation. Note that, after a rotation of $\pi/2$ radians any point of $S$ will have shifted into the square on the left. Thus to work out repeated rotations in $\mathbb{T}$, each $r$ must be followed by a $t$, and the problem reduces to showing $$trtrtrtr(z)=z.$$ This is straightforward: $$tr(z)=iz+1$$ $$tr(iz+1)=-z+i+1$$ $$tr(-z+i+1)=-iz+i$$ $$tr(-iz+i)=z.$$

This setup also works for the case that the fundamental region is a rhombus $R$ with angles $\pi/3$ and $2\pi/3$. Some extra care is required this time, but not much, and it unearths a neat connection between tori and the roots of unity.

This time, let $$t(z)=z+\omega,\quad t_2(z)=z+\omega^2$$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{i2\pi}{3}}$ is a cube root of unity. We consider the rotation $r$ of $\pi/3$ radians about the origin. We will show $r$ maps $\Gamma$-orbits to $\Gamma$-orbits and thus is an isometry. Let $a=e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$.

For a rotated point $rz$ $$\Gamma rz=\{az+n\omega+m\omega^2:n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$ Let $z'\in\Gamma z$, then $$rz'=az+aN\omega+aM\omega^2$$ $$=az-N-\frac{M}{\omega^2}$$ $$=az+(\omega+\omega^2)N-M\omega $$ $$=az+(N-M)\omega+N\omega^2 .$$ Thus $rz'\in\Gamma rz$ and we conclude $r$ induces an isometry in $\mathbb{T}$.

So, we are left to show the order of $r$ in $\mathbb{T}$ is $6$.  Let $z$ be a point in the upper half of $R$, then the figure below shows that $tr^2(z)$ is a point in the upper half of $R$. Hence, we need only show $$tr^2tr^2tr^2(z)=z,$$ which follows once again from some simple properties of cube roots of unity: $$tr^2(z)=\omega z+\omega$$ $$tr^2(\omega z+\omega)=\omega^2z+\omega^2+\omega$$ $$tr^2(\omega^2z+\omega^2+\omega)=z+1+\omega+\omega^2=z.$$ The case for $z$ in the lower half being essentially the same, we conclude the result.

[image]

Clearly, Tsemo's proof via group actions is a slicker path to the result. There is something nice, however, about "seeing" the two geometries differ and connecting this to the roots of unity. I doubt this method would work for general $n^{th}$-roots of unity (maybe $6^{th}$), since really we were exploiting symmetries of *regular* tilings of the plane, of which there are only three (square, equilateral triangle, and hexagon). Basically, we used the  neat algebraic properties of the Gaussian and Eisenstein rings.